# Glassfish in real world

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, glassfish, production

Are there any companies/web-sites that use Glassfish in production? I am new to J2EE and deploy JRuby on Rails alongside a JAX-WS Metro application in Glassfish v3 Prelude. Sometimes the quirks make me go WTF and rip my hair out.

I haven't had experience with Apache Tomcat and was wondering if it makes sense to switch to Tomcat, as Glassfish might not be yet ready for serious development?

Comment: The recent 3.0.1 release, should hopefully allow for more installations as many bugs were fixed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For GlassFish in the real world, check out http://blogs.oracle.com/stories.

Here's a couple of quick-hits of JRuby on GlassFish production stories:

- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/arungupta/archive/2008/04/jruby_and_glass.html
- http://blog.linkedin.com/2008/08/19/jdbc-connection-pooling-for-rails-on-glassfish/

Other useful resources:

- http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=JRuby
- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/arungupta/
  (Lots of JRuby on GlassFish posts)

Hope this helps

John Clingan, GlassFish Group Product Manager

Answer (score 5):

I have about 50 Glassfish instances in production and "production test". My only piece of advice would be "don't run it on Windows". See [GlassFish on Windows vs RedHat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951723/glassfish-on-windows-vs-redhat) for the main reason why.

Answer (score 4):

The company I'm working in switched from Tomcat to Glassfish when we needed JMS for asynchronous messages. Instead of going with an external JMS solution into Tomcat, we chose to use Glassfish. [OpenMQ](http://mq.dev.java.net) - which is used by Glassfish - is actually a good JMS solution which offers many features with regards to clustering and high availability. I think that the stack Sun has with MySQL, OpenMQ and Glassfish is an interesting stack of software.

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish is a Java EE application server, whilst Tomcat is not, as discussed [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2008/jw-01-tomcat6.html)

However, if you use Spring along with Tomcat, then you have the best of both worlds.

See more discussion [here](http://www.jroller.com/cardsharp/entry/tomcat_vs_app_server).

Answer (score 0):

See page #45 "Who's using GlassFish in production?" here: https://slx.sun.com/1179275180

and

http://kenai.com/ is running under GlassFish Web Stack or GlassFish LAMP enabled.